# Unable to call a function multiple times in my python program

Tags: python, debugging

My introductory python course for this semester has asked us to create a tic-tac-toe program with a specific set of functions we must design- I've gotten everything done and created a working random tic-tac-toe game, but when trying to run the game multiple times in a row it refuses to:

```
import random as rand
init_board = ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'] #blank board
win_combos = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]] #combinations of indexes of 3 in a row
def print_board(board): #prints the formatted board
    print(board[0], board[1], board[2])
    print(board[3], board[4], board[5])
    print(board[6], board[7], board[8])

def open_spots(board): #gathers the open spots on a board to determine where moves can be made
    open_spots = []
    for cell in range(board.__len__()):
        if board[cell] == '-':
            open_spots.append(cell)
    return open_spots #list with index numbers of blank spaces

def random_move(board, symbol): #a random move selector for the cmputer, with the current game board and X or O
    new_board = board
    #print(new_board)
    to_insert = rand.choice(open_spots(new_board))
    new_board.insert(to_insert, symbol)
    new_board.pop(to_insert+1)
    return new_board #returns the new game board after the move at the end

def check_three(board, indx1, indx2, indx3): #checks 3 indexes for matching values
    if board[indx1] == 'X' and board[indx2] == 'X' and board[indx3] == 'X':
        return 'X'
    elif board[indx1] == 'O' and board[indx2] == 'O' and board[indx3] == 'O':
        return 'O'
    else: return '-'

def winner(board): #checks all 3-in-a-row indexes using the above function to determine if anyone has won
    val = None
    for i in range(win_combos.__len__()):
        if check_three(board, win_combos[i][0], win_combos[i][1], win_combos[i][2]) == 'X':
            val = 'X'
        elif check_three(board, win_combos[i][0], win_combos[i][1], win_combos[i][2]) == 'O':
            val = 'O'
    if board.count('-') < 1 and val == None:
            val = 'D'
    elif val == None:
        val = '-'
    return val

def tic_tac_toe_with_player(): #ignore
    player_symbol = input('Would you like to be X or O?' )
    comp_symbol = ''
    if player_symbol == 'X' or player_symbol == 'x':
        player_symbol == 'X'
        comp_symbol = 'O'
    elif player_symbol == 'O' or player_symbol == 'o':
        player_symbol = 'X'
        comp_symbol = 'X'
    else: 
        print('Oh no! Thats not an option.')
        tic_tac_toe_with_player()
    
def tic_tac_toe(): #plays tic tac toe
    tic_tac_toe_board = init_board #board
    comp_symbol = ['X', 'O'] #computers symbols for placing
    n = 0
    while winner(tic_tac_toe_board) == '-': #while theres no wins
        tic_tac_toe_board = random_move(tic_tac_toe_board, comp_symbol[n]) #reassign the board with the new game board after a move (works)
        if n==1: n = 0 #other player goes
        else: n = 1
        print_board(tic_tac_toe_board) #visuals for the game
    return winner(tic_tac_toe_board) #returns who won

def tic_tac_100(): #any num of games at once
    x_wins = 0 #win trackers
    o_wins = 0
    d_wins = 0
    winner_counts = '' 
    for i in range(int(input("How many games do you want played? "))): #for loop, supposed to run tic_tac_toe() a bunch
        winner_counts = tic_tac_toe()
        if winner_counts == 'X': #check who won, add a counter for that players win or if its a draw, add a counter for draw
            x_wins +=1
        elif winner_counts == 'O':
             o_wins +=1
        else:
            d_wins +=1
    return 'x-wins: ' + str(x_wins), 'o-wins: ' + str(o_wins), 'draws: ' + str(d_wins) #returns a statement of the wins and draws that occurred


print(tic_tac_100())
```

I originally thought I was just getting the same random move set every time due to issues with the random module, but that wasn't the case and wouldn't fix it no matter what I tried- it seems when I have

```
print(tic_tac_toe())
print(tic_tac_toe())
```

it still only returns one game of tic tac toe- so its only running the function once. I cannot understand for the life of me why this would be. The final objective is to get the data on 100 games (ie, the last function). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `tic_tac_toe_board = init_board` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: `tic_tac_toe_board = init_board` doesn't make a copy, you're actually playing the game on the initial board.  After the first game is finished, any attempt to start another game is going to immediately finish, because the board is already full.

Comment: Do you know how to copy a list? Also, why are you calling *board.__len__()*? Sure, it works but why? Why are you using recursion in *tic_tac_toe_with_player()*?